# Recyclerview not loading images

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview, android-volley

i'm trying to get images from url using volley but its not working 
at the time of loading data app is crashing ... but when i remove the imageloader
evertything is loading correctly like text data ...

here is my adapter class

```
public class RecyclerViewDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private Pants context;
public ImageLoader mImageLoader;

//List of superHeroes
List<ListOfData> superHeroes;

public RecyclerViewDataAdapter(List<ListOfData> superHeroes, Pants context){
    super();
    //Getting all the superheroes
    this.superHeroes = superHeroes;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ListOfData superHero =  superHeroes.get(position);

    mImageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
    mImageLoader.get(superHero.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView1, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

    holder.imageView1.setImageUrl(superHero.getImageUrl(), mImageLoader);
    holder.textViewName1.setText(superHero.getName());
    //holder.textViewRank.setText(String.valueOf(superHero.getRank()));
    //holder.textViewRealName.setText(superHero.getRealName());
    //holder.textViewCreatedBy.setText(superHero.getCreatedBy());
    //holder.textViewFirstAppearance.setText(superHero.getFirstAppearance());

    String powers = "";

   /* for(int i = 0; i<superHero.getPowers().size(); i++){
        powers+= superHero.getPowers().get(i);
    }*/

    //holder.textViewPowers.setText(powers);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return superHeroes.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public NetworkImageView imageView1;
    public NetworkImageView imageView2;
    public TextView textViewName1;
    public TextView textViewName2;
    public TextView textViewRank;
    public TextView textViewRealName;
    public TextView textViewCreatedBy;
    public TextView textViewFirstAppearance;
    public TextView textViewPowers;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView1 = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        imageView2 = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail2);
       textViewName1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_title_one);
        textViewName2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_title_two);
        /* textViewRank= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRank);
        textViewRealName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRealName);
        textViewCreatedBy= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCreatedBy);
        textViewFirstAppearance= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFirstAppearance);
        textViewPowers= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPowers);
        */
    }
}
```

}

and the JSON part

```
public class Pants extends Fragment {
private Pants context;

//Creating a List of superheroes
public List<ListOfData> listSuperHeroes;

//Creating Views
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;


public Pants() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tshirts_pants_shirts, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


    //Calling method to get data
    getData();
    return view;
}


private void getData() {
    //Showing a progress dialog
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading Data", "Please wait...", false, false);

    //Creating a json array request
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(ProductConfig.DATA_URL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //Dismissing progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();

                    //calling method to parse json array
                    parseData(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //Creating request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

//This method will parse json data
private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
    listSuperHeroes = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        ListOfData superHero = new ListOfData();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            superHero.setImageUrl(json.getString(ProductConfig.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
            superHero.setName(json.getString(ProductConfig.TAG_NAME));
            //superHero.setRank(json.getInt(ProductConfig.TAG_RANK));
            //superHero.setRealName(json.getString(ProductConfig.TAG_REAL_NAME));
            //superHero.setCreatedBy(json.getString(ProductConfig.TAG_CREATED_BY));
            //superHero.setFirstAppearance(json.getString(ProductConfig.TAG_FIRST_APPEARANCE));

            ArrayList<String> powers = new ArrayList<String>();

            JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(ProductConfig.TAG_POWERS);

            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                powers.add(((String) jsonArray.get(j)) + "\n");
            }
            superHero.setPowers(powers);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        listSuperHeroes.add(superHero);
    }
    //Finally initializing our adapter
    adapter = new RecyclerViewDataAdapter(listSuperHeroes, this);

    //Adding adapter to recyclerview
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



}
```

}

here is error that is showing

```
Process: com.example.aninesoft.meltwishbeta, PID: 23012
                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                    at com.aninesoft.meltwishbeta.RecyclerViewDataAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewDataAdapter.java:45)
                                                                                    at com.aninesoft.meltwishbeta.RecyclerViewDataAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewDataAdapter.java:19)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5277)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5310)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4568)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4461)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1962)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1371)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1334)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:563)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2847)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3145)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14832)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4640)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14832)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4640)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1627)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14832)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4640)
                                                                                    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1034)
                                                                                    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:744)
                                                                                    at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                                                                                    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1180)
                                                                                    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:757)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14832)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4640)
                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14832)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4640)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14832)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4640)
                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14832)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4640)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14832)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4640)
                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14832)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4640)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1996)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1753)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5739)
                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer
```

Comment: which is the line 45 in your adapter ?

Comment: this is 
mImageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

Comment: what is MyApplication ?

Comment: can't u able to use picasso to display image????

Comment: MyApplication is  volleysingleton class reference from develpoer.android.com

Comment: Use `Glide` or `Picasso`.

Comment: no i can't coz i m following a tutorial from a website and he uses a volley

Comment: @johnmiller You context is of Pants type, is that what it is supposed to be ? Doesn't it need to be Context context ?

Comment: its giving me error when i changed the type of context

Comment: What param does your getInstance() method receive?

Comment: i forgot to add MyApplication class in Manifest 

but now its working fine after adding in manifest 

thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

make the getImageLoader method non-static

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance(context).getImageLoader()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you try showing the image before it was downloaded?

Try loading a dummy-image until the real image is downloaded.